# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier ‘com.github.krzyzanowskim.OpenSSL’ is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xcode, native

When I try to upload my app after successfully archived it is showing me this error couldn't connect to App Store..can any one help me out

Comment: try to post code snippet here so everyone can help thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community, I thought you were a *robot*!